# How to omit checking for SqlNullValueException in Mysql Connector/NET

Tags: c#, mysql, null

When reading data from the reader I have to check each parameter that allows for null values in the database whether it is threw a NullValueException. Especially I have to check each value with a separate **try/catch** because I still want to parse the next value it the first one was null. In C# some classes have a tryParse(key, out value) function, which returns a boolean on success, but I didn't find it for Connector/NET.  Is there any way to shorten the following statements?

```
Product product;
try {
    product = new Product(
        reader.GetString("product_id"),
        reader.GetDateTime("starttime")
        );
    try {
        product.EndTime = reader.GetDateTime("endtime");
    } catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException) { }
    try {
        product.Description = reader.GetString("description");
    } catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException) { }
    try {
        product.Type = reader.GetString("type");
    } catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException) { }
} catch (MySqlException ex) {
    throw ex;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this pattern with SqlDataReader, I imagine it should be the same with MySQL Connector/Net.

```
product.EndTime = reader["endtime"] as DateTime? ?? DateTime.MinValue;
product.Description = reader["description"] as string;
product.Type = reader["type"] as string;
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, this works well for me. And it is also much shorter than my previous code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The MySqlDataReader has a method "IsDBNull(int i)" that you can use to check for null values.

Comment: unfortunately then i need to know the column number, but im referencing columns by name.